# How to fix npm ERR! peer dep missing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I was checking the list of npm packages installed with

> npm list --depth 0

and after the list of npm packages I found these two lines, please tell me why these errors are getting shown and how to fix them?

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: chartist@^0.10.1, required by
> react-chartist@0.14.4
>
> npm ERR! peer dep missing: @babel/core@^7.13.0, required by
> @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4

Answer (score 0):

Peer dependencies are needed if you publish your package. I found the yarn doc easier to understand but npm doc is here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies

There are 2 ways to fix this error. Either install `chartist` and `@babel/core` or upgrade to npm 7 and run npm install again